# Merge sorted files without knowing file names

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix, gzip

I have a directory of gzipped files that are all sorted. I do not know how many files are in the directory. I would like to merge these files into a single file. I had been going about it like this:

`find . -type f | xargs zcat | sort`

However when I add the `-m` flag, it just concatenates the files one after another. Is there a way to use `sort -m` to merge all the sorted files in a directory?

Thanks!

I would like to note that @chepner's solution works perfectly for non-zipped files.

Comment: The `sort` command cannot take zipped files as input.

Comment: `sort -m` doesn't sort; it *only* merges its pre-sorted input files. When you read from standard input, you only have *one* input file. You simply do not need `-m` in this context.

Comment: I would like to simply merge the files since I know they are all sorted, is that possible?

Comment: So, for example, you have `log.3.gz`, whose data are followed by `log.2.gz`, then `log.1.gz`?  Your `find` command may not out files in the order you expect.

Comment: The order the files go to sort does not matter. I just need to figure out how to get sort to recognize that I'm merging many files, and not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer!

`find . -type f | awk '{print "<(gzip -cd "$0")"}' | tr "\n" " " | (echo -n sort -m  " "; cat -; echo) | bash`

This finds all the files in the directory, and send them as arguments to a sort command, replacing newlines with spaces along the way. Thanks for everyone's help in getting here!

Answer (score 3):

To merge pre-sorted files, you need to supply the names as arguments, not the data as standard input. Assuming you don't have *that* many files, just use

```
sort -m *
```

Comment: The files are `gzip`d though. It'll probably require building or evaling some process substitutions.

Comment: Yes, that is the root of my problem.

Comment: You can concatenate two gzipped files together to make one longer gzipped file. If you don't actually need to *sort*, then `cat log*.gz > bigfile.gz` would seem to be fine.

Comment: `echo hello > A; echo world > B; gzip A B; cat A.gz B.gz | zcat`

Comment: I do need the final file to be sorted.

Comment: @MattAdelman, you said in another comment, "*I would like to simply merge the files since I know they are all sorted*". Which is it?

Comment: By merge I mean merge in the merge-sort sense. So when you merge sorted files, the result is still sorted.